# Does the Rds(on) of a MOSFET vary based on source-drain voltage?

Tags: mosfet, low-voltage

The Rds(on) of a MOSFET decreases when you apply higher gate voltage, but does it typically vary based on the source-drain voltage?

I will be using a MOSFET to switch very low voltages (10's to 1000's of µV) and was wondering if normal MOSFETs will work as long as the gate voltage is high or if the low source-drain voltage means I will need something special.

Comment: Are these AC voltages? maybe you want a CMOS switch. There will always be a glitch from the  Vgs dV/dt onto the signal from Miller capacitance. You must define all input and output specs for V(f), Z(f) and load and switch rate. Is it a break-before-make switch? Or just a MUX?

Comment: Do you care about  charge injection, which can cause a change to ±ΔVOUT (a few millivolts), thereby affecting the accuracy of your design

Comment: These are DC voltages. The use-case is measuring current in the range of 1-1000 na/ua/ma by measuring the voltage drop across a shunt resistor (to minimize impact on the device being measured the drop will be < 2 mv or so). I have 3 different resistors for different current ranges, and want to automatically switch between them, that's where the MOSFET (or other?) switch is needed - the current flow through one resistor should be allowed, with the other 2 switched off.

Comment: RdsOn needed is determined by smallest R value. and leakage by the largest R value. What are they? Did you say if these are low side or high side or dont care

Comment: Planned resistor values are 10k, 10, 0.01. Leakage would be a concern, but if I do high side switching and use a differential ADC with enough channels so that I can connect both sides of the resistor directly to their own ADC pin without the MOSFET in the way, I figured I shouldn't have to worry about RdsOn even for the 0.01 ohm resistor.

Comment: So is the end result computing  resistance or current?  10k*1nA= 10uV  why not use a DAC with Howland CC

Comment: End result is computing current. Yup 10k for the na range, 10uV per nA, sending that to an ADC that has an internal gain of 128 and 16 bits output, vref of 2.048, I think that works out to a resolution of about 0.25 uV per bit.

Comment: So what is the maximum error tolerance and DUT max R value?  10k?

Comment: The ADC I'm looking at has a typical error of 0.015%, I'm hoping to not compound that too much - ideally not more than 0.1%, though consistency is more important than absolute accuracy. The DUT will be various microcontrollers / low lower timers that use a few mA (or possibly a few hundred mA) while awake, but single digit uA or even low tens of nA while in low power mode.

Comment: ok then R= 5V/1n = 5GOhm Equiv  or  3.3V/10nA= 330M with 0.1% error means 330 GOhm leakage equiv or 1000x  CLearly a better way is possible

Comment: It's worth mentioning that "low source-drain voltages" is specifically what the (ideally zero) \$R_{DS,on}\$ parameter is meant to ensure. With a low \$R_{DS,on}\$ comes a low \$V_{DS}\$, for a given \$I_D\$.

Comment: Is a mechanical relay the only way then, or are there other things I should be researching?

Comment: What you might have said instead is...

**How can I accurately (0.1%) measure uC sleep and operating currents?**

in order to measure power consumption from Vbat ranging from _Vmin to Vmax?

**x nA deep sleep mode mode**

x uA sleep mode
x mA operating for __ms every _s

Comment: READ this first about guarding http://www.techni-tool.com/site/ARTICLE_LIBRARY/Keithley-Low%20Current%20Measurements.pdf

Comment: I would use an integrator to measure low current with offset null. then output can be full scale with variable time interval S&H then dump integrator

Comment: It looks like https://lowpowerlab.com/guide/currentranger/?view=all is basically what I had in mind - measuring down to nA with an accuracy of 0.05% with automated switching between ranges. They're doing it with opamps and a multimeter to read the output rather than a built in ADC. I wonder what they're using for the switching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question *body* is "not significantly".  The answer to your question *title* is "yes" -- but unless you have a really truly oddball FET, or you need insane accuracy, you don't need to worry.

RDS on is a parameter of a FET that's operating at low source to drain currents.  It *specifically* refers to a range of voltages where the thing is acting like a resistor, and \$v_{ds} \simeq R_{DS_{on}} i_{ds}\$.  The lower your \$v_{ds}\$ compared to the threshold voltage, the better the approximation.  Your \$v_{ds}\$ is significantly lower than the threshold voltage of most FETs, so you're OK.

Comment: he wants insane accuracy of 1na and 1uV..e.g. how to design a 5 digit Keithley nA meter in 5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

The drain to source voltage if you are using the MOS as a switch would be very low, so it won't affect the Rds on. If you are only switching voltages in the range of 10 to 1000 uV then the body bias or back gate effect would be less, so the threshold of MOS won't vary much, hence the low Rds on.

Answer (score 0):

> John S. said *The Rds(on) of a MOSFET decreases when you apply higher gate voltage, but does it typically vary based on the source-drain voltage?*

What he might have said instead is...

- How can I accurately (0.1%) measure uC sleep and operating currents?

  - in order to measure power consumption from Vbat ranging from _Vmin to Vmax?
  - x nA deep sleep mode mode
  - x uA sleep mode
  - x mA operating for __ms every _s